# mySQL dropdown using PHP does not display options from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I looked at some other questions online and on here related to this, but none seem to really encounter my error exactly.

I wrote my PHP code and implemented it into my HTML, I get the dropdown box appearing, but it doesn't actually want to display any values. Is there any implementations or fixes I should include in my code? How do I get it to work?

My database is called: `Treatments`

My column in the database that I want displayed is called: `Treatment`

`treatment_dropdown.php`

```
<?php

    $hostname = 'host_name';
    $dbname = 'database_name';
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';

    $con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
    $db=mysql_select_db($dbname,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());


    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Treatments`";

    $result = mysql_query($con, $query);
    $options = "";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $options = $options . "<option>$row[1]</option>";
    }


?>
```

HTML:

```
<body>  
    <select>
        <?php 
            echo $options;
        ?>
    </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the HTML in a seperate file (not `treatment_dropdown.php`)? If it is, have you `include`d `treatment_dropdown.php` in your HTML file?

Comment: Don't you want backticks instead of single-quotes around the table name?

Comment: Yes it's a separate file. I have included it as a class but I don't think thats right, and that's what might be causing it.

Comment: Your options also have no `value` attribute. You seriously need to read some tutorials.

Comment: @developerwjk Perhaps explain it instead of hating? I'm new to PHP.

Comment: `<option value='1'>First choice</option>` Being new to PHP is precisely why you should read some tutorials rather than ask every simple thing on SO. Not hating, just trying to help you waste less time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider changing this line:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'Treatments'";
```

to use backticks instead of single quotes like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Treatments`";
```

In my test query I got an error because of this, let me know if that helps.

Comment: I just did, and edited the post. Unfortunately that does not change it :(

Comment: That really should work unless there is a problem with your connection, can you attempt to run the query in phpmyadmin or in a terminal? If it works, then we can narrow it down to your connection code.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<?php include 'treatment_dropdown.php'; ?>` to the top of your HTML file. This should give you access to the the `$options` string so it can be used in that file. Note that in order for this to work, `treatment_dropdown.php` needs to be in the same directory as your HTML file. If it is not, the include statement will need to be changed to reflect the appropriate file path.

Comment: Gives me this: `mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given`

Comment: and this: `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given`

Comment: Your arguments to `mysql_query` are in the wrong order.

Comment: Everything works now, Thank You! Thumbs UP!

Comment: Glad I could help! By the way, please do heed the advice from the other answers and comments about not using the outdated mysql functions.

Comment: Yes will do! How would I go about changing it? I don't really know how to...

Comment: I recommend PDO. Checking out some of the examples from the PHP documentation should get you started. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) for creating a connection, and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) for executing your queries as prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use mysql_*() functions, they are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.
2. No matter which library use use to access mysql, always check for errors within the sql code separately. Errors in the sql code do not result in errors in the php code.
3. In this particular case the problem is that you included the table in single quotes instead of backticks.

The correct code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Treatments`";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your PHP file should look like:

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$dbname   = 'Treatments';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

$con = mysql_connect( $hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

/* No single quotes needed for the table name. */
$query = "SELECT * FROM Treatments";

/* First parameter should be $query not $con */
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
$options = "";

/* Check if no results exist. */
if ( !$result ) {
    die( "NO results found." );
}

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $options .= "<option>$row[treatment]</option>";
}
```

?>

Notes:

1. dont use mysql_* functions, they're not secure, use PDO instead.
2. your table name does not need to be wrapped in single quotes.
3. mysql_query expects parameter 1 to be the query not the DB connection.
4. you should probably check if no results are found.